# How to convert an array of Strings to a list

Tags: arrays, swift, arraylist, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have an array of Strings and I want to use that as a list.

I followed this example but I didn't get for an array. [Link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-list-of-dynamic-items)

My current code is given below:

```
    struct ListOfPeripherals: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var peripheralName: String
    }

    struct RestaurantRow: View {
        var peripheralFromBLE: ListOfPeripherals

        var body: some View {

    // List to be implemented here

        }

    func getListOfAlphabets() -> [String] {
        let listOfAlphabets = [A,B,C,D,E]
        return listOfAlphabets
    }
  }
```

Comment: follow the tutorial! it works as expected. You have to understand that List mentioned there is SwiftUI container (aka table view)

Comment: hey @user3441734 I tried to understand the swiftUI list view but every data is converted to struct and is assigned as a variable name. Later the row is made using the same variable name. I tried doing a different approach with Dictionary I was able to get a solution, but for an array, I'm not getting a list.

Comment: in the tutorial there is an array of restaurants and this array is presented in a SwiftUI.List . i suggest you to go back there and check the tutorial from the beginning, to understand the basics of SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to convert your Array of String objects to make the List work. You should describe your error pasting it along with your code to get helped faster. So, this is my assumption of your concept of error.

The Array type is fine, but however, his Elements, in this case the strings, need to be identified. This means you have to conform your String to the Identifiable protocol, and providing an id property which must be unique (a simple UUID object will do the trick).

In your code, the function getListOfAlphabets returns an array of Strings which cannot be used. If you were to use a [ListOfPeripherals] array that would work because it conforms to the protocol. I think you got a bit of confusion and you are basically returning an array of wrong type.